# Apache gzip with chucked encoding

Tags: apache-2.2, compression

I'm expiriencing some problem with one of my data source services.
As it says in HTTP response headers it's running on Apache-Coyote/1.1.
Server gives responses with Transfer-Encoding: chunked, here sample response:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Content-Type: text/xml;charset=utf-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Tue, 30 Mar 2010 06:13:52 GMT
```

And problem is when I'm requesting server to send gzipped request it often sends not full response. I recieve response, see that last chunk recived, but then after ungzipping I see that response is partial.

So my question is: is it common apache issue? maybe one of it's mod_deflate plugins or something? Ask questions if you need more info.

Thanks.

Comment: What are you using to read HTTP? Chunked encoding is often poorly implemented/unimplemented.

Comment: I did it myself actually :) And i can asure that I recieve full response. I recieve 0 chunk size, then \r\n\r\n which means this is the end as it said in HTTP Specification atleast.